# Header always edit Set-Cookie not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I am using Apache 2.4.6 on an up-to-date installation of CentOS 7.9.  I have tried all variations of setting a header like below (adding/removing quotes, changing the regular expression, etc.) but the Set-Cookie header is never modified when sent to the user.  Every article I find trying to accomplish this says it works but it just does not work for me.

```
Header always set TestBefore 1
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"
Header always set TestAfter 1
```

Both the before and after headers are sent but the Set-Cookie header is never modified.  Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Set-Cookie header is being set in the `onsuccess` condition, not the `always` condition. Those are different sets. You need

```
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"
```

Or just leave out `onsuccess`, since it's the default. See [Header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header).